# How to make sure a method is executed only once on every worker node?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Suppose I have a method to be executed once on every worker node.

The following code is what I have come up with to achieve this goal, but it seems that the method is executed twice on the same worker node(there are a master and two worker nodes altogether).

```
    val noOfExecs = sparkSession.sparkContext.getExecutorMemoryStatus.keys.size
    val results = sparkSession.sparkContext
      .parallelize(0 until noOfExecs, noOfExecs)
      .map { _ =>
        new SomeClass().doSomething()
      }
      .cache()
   results.count()
```

How can I make sure that the method is executed only once on every worker node?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you've confused yourself in drawing the conclusion. Why do you say the method is executed twice on the same worker node?
a few things needs to be clarified for spark:

1. the noOfExecs by using the method `sparkSession.sparkContext.getExecutorMemoryStatus.keys.size` will return the total number of executors plus driver. which will be 3 if you have two workers/executors.
2. breaking down your code into a few chunks, first a `data` set to be parallelized out to the spark cluster, it is basically an array/range of integers. (0,1,2).  Note you can not really control which integer get `sent` to which worker.
3. and you map over the integer(s), so there are 3 values in the `data` set across all 2 workers, and you ask the worker to do something. ( below I've modified it to print to the WORKERs stdout - console output, so when you check the WORKER log, you know which data is executed on that worker.)
4. the rest of `cache` or `results.count()` are just noise.
5. a method will be executed once on each worker, if you use method like `map`. so you do not have to ensure this, spark should.

see below. and you should be able to check worker's log. in my test, 1 work log has this

```
on worker, this method is executed for data number: 1, happy sharing
```

and the other worker has this:

```
on worker, this method is executed for data number: 0, happy sharing

on worker, this method is executed for data number: 2, happy sharing
```

below is your code being modified.

```
class SomeClass()
{
  def doSomething(x:Int) = {
    println(s"on worker, this method is executed for data number: $x, happy sharing")   

  }
}

// below return 3 for 1 driver, 2 executors/workers cluster setup
val driverAndWorkers = spark.sparkContext.getExecutorMemoryStatus
val noOfExecs = driverAndWorkers.keys.size

//below is basicaly '0,1,2'
val data = 0 until noOfExecs
val rddOfInt = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data,noOfExecs) //, noOfExecs can be removed. in this case/topic, it does not matter how you partition the RDD.

val results = rddOfInt
  .map {     x =>
        new SomeClass().doSomething(x)
  }
.cache()
results.count()
```

Comment: Is there a guarantee that the tasks for an rdd with n partitions will be distributed evenly over n executors? Or is it only very likely?